# Expected declaration on a simple condition

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have made a rooter at the start for my application in order to get a better attribution between all my views. I just introduced the login system which use the userDefauts **Logged**. Then, when I start to compile, it gets me "Expected declaration", where I am wrong?

Here is my code :

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView : View {

    @State var rooterPage: Int
    var defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    // New user (also this is where I got my error "Expected declaration"
    if defaults.bool(forKey: "Logged") != true {
         rooterPage = 1
    }
    // Logged user
    else {
         rooterPage = 3
    }

   var body: some View {
      VStack{
        if rooterPage == 1 {
           WelcomeView(rooterPage: $rooterPage)
        }
        else if rooterPage == 2 {
           Register(rooterPage: $rooterPage).transition(.slide)
        }
        else if rooterPage == 3 {
           Home(rooterPage: $rooterPage).transition(.slide)
        }
      }

  }
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Give your property initialization inside a method, like this:

```
init() {
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Logged") != true {
         rooterPage = 1
    }
    // Logged user
    else {
         rooterPage = 3
    }
}
```

Comment: So I should write a function RooterPage and call the init() inside? Could you develop a bit more your code please? Because my variable **rooterPage** is subject to modification after and I guess that init() will be called only one time.

Comment: Since it's an `@State` you can change it's state whenever it changes and the UI will respond accordingly. So you don't have to worry about setting an initial value.

Comment: You may need to follow some tutorials and documentation to follow through the SwiftUI, your code could use a serious amount of improvements. I'd recommend hacking with swift's SwiftUI article's.